# 14.04 fails to reboot after /var migration to separate partition

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, mount

I have Dell inspiron 7559 laptop with 14.04, kernel 4.4.0-34. I have two hard drives - 256G SSD and 1T HDD. One of the good practices I tried to apply is to separate the potentially big folders as  /home, /tmp and /var on the HDD. Following [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving) instruction I succeeded to mount /home on a separate partition on the HDD. It was /dev/sdb2. On the same way I mounted /var on /dev/sdb3. But when I restarted the laptop the reboot process failed and stop. I found following message:

```
....
umount2: Device or resource busy
umount: /dev/sdb3 busy - remounted read-only
....
```

This is the picture of the shutdown messages:

[image: This is the picture of the shutdown messages]

I tried to umount this device, even with -f option but with no success.
During the shutdown process I can find which process is using the device. In the other hand I have no idea what is the relation between CPU warning below and the issue I'm talking about. Any suggestions?

Edit:
Here's the content of /etc/fstab

```
UUID=fd59d724-ba0a-4933-b16d-5b1c719018f9 /  ext4  errors=remount-ro 0       1    
UUID=9FF3-487E  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults,discard,noatime   0   1    
UUID=1dca912d-cfda-49b9-b753-ef171c319838 none  swap    sw     0   0    
UUID=0c748e4a-ae06-4705-9084-7b749b3bfe55 /home ext4 defaults  0   2    
UUID=e14c934c-698c-4446-b07b-5617cd0213c2 /var ext4 defaults   0   0
```

Comment: Can you post the content of your `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: Sure, I made an edit in the primary note

Comment: See this answer - http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/107887